# Which is better, single speed or three speed?

Tags: single-speed

Which is better, single speed or three speed? I am 45 and buying an adult trike because I never learned to ride a bike when I was younger.  I don't know if I get a single speed or three speed?

Comment: Unless it's totally flat where you live, I'd advise getting a multi-gear bike.  Trikes are now available with fairly wide gear ranges, if you're willing to pay -- how many gears depends on what range of hills you want to handle and how hard you want to work.  (But why not borrow a regular adult bike and try to learn to ride it first, before going for the trike?)

Comment: At 45, learning to ride can still be VERY fun and soon you'll be glad you didn't go for the trike, since bicycles are much more versatile, easy to store, easy to go upstairs, etc. There are some questions/answers about how to learn.

Comment: If you go for a trike, go for a recumbent trike, those are fun to ride and not have the 'I can not cope with a two wheel bike' stigma.

Answer (score 6):

Because of your interest, age and desire to ride a trike, I would recommend a 3 speed. Trikes are very heavy and if you are new to biking you may need an easier gear than what a single speed will offer stock on most trikes.

Answer (score 5):

I have a trike that was single speed; I found it very difficult to ride on an upgrade.

I've converted it to five speed with a Sturmey Archer kit and it made a world of a difference.

I love to ride a bicycle, however at age 75, my balance is not very good anymore, that is why I've switched to a trike. I would never tell you to ride a trike, my preference is a bicycle unless you have physical limitations.